# python absolute XPath returns empty list, generic query better?

Tags: python, html, list, xpath

I wish to get text from a html page using XPath.
The particular text is in the td to right of Description: (inside th element) from the url in the source.

In the first call (commented out) I have tried absolute path from XPath taken from Chrome inspector but I get an empty list.
The next call works and gives the heading:
"Description:"

I require a generic XPath query that would take a text heading (like "Description:") and give text value of the td next to it.

```
url = 'http://datrack.canterbury.nsw.gov.au/cgi/datrack.pl?cmd=download&id=ZiFfLxV6W1xHWBN1UwR5SVVSAV0GXUZUcGFGHhAyTykQAG5CWVcARwM='
page = requests.get(url)
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

# desc = tree.xpath('//*[@id="documentpreview"]/div[1]/table[1]/tbody/tr[2]/td//text()')

desc = tree.xpath("//text()[contains(., 'Description:')]")
```

I have tried variations of XPath queries but my knowledge is not deep enough.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `//*[contains(text(), 'Description:')]` to find tags whose text contains `Description:`, and use `following-sibling::td` to find following siblings which are `td` tags:

```
In [180]: tree.xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Description:')]/following-sibling::td/text()")
Out[180]: ['Convert existing outbuilding into a recreational area with bathroom and kitchenette']
```

Comment: I tested and it worked! 
Thank you for pointing me to this sibling notation unutbu.